# (Visual Studio) How can I tell which parts of my c++ program ran and which didn't?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I keep getting an exception but the place where it breaks doesn't help me. I need to figure out what the last ran line of code is in the main.

Is there something that highlights lines of code that run? Or some king of similar debug feature?

edit: visual studio 2015 community. I also have 2013 pro

Comment: can you look at the stack trace?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that. That helps, thanks

Comment: It looks like I can't upvote a comment though

Answer (score 0):

Press F-11 it allows you to "step into" your code. And veiw what the computer is doing line by line, it will show you exactly wich line your crashing on. And usually why